# WPF minimizing window into bottom of parrent window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I try to make a "email messenger". I have two windows. Main window, there is ribbon with bookmarks and one button (New message). This button invoke second window NewMessage. The Mainwindow is owner of the NewMessage window.

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewMessage newmessage = new NewMessage();
        newmessage.Show();
    }
}
```

}

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Messenger.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Messenger"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="New Message" Height="20" Width="80
            " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="35,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click" />
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="254" Margin="34,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="461" Background="{x:Null}" SelectedIndex="1">
        <TabItem Header="Delivered" Visibility="Hidden" Width="80">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Delivered" Visibility="Visible" Width="80">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Sent" Width="80">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Trash" Width="80">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

NewMessage:

```
public partial class NewMessage : Window
{
    public NewMessage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

NewMessage XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Messenger.NewMessage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Messenger"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="NewMessage" Height="351.047" Width="814.398">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="23*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="243*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Komu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Předmět" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RichTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="243" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="806" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="Sem zadejte text zprávy"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Odeslat" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,5,90,0"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Storno" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="0,5,10,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

I would like to, when I minimize NewMessage window, this window minimize to the bottom of MainWindow "taskbar". If you know gmail, there is the same principle. Any idea?

Comment: You are talking about `MDI` which is not available in `WPF`, however [`Avalon Dock`](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) has something similar.

Comment: How is Qt related to this question? If it isn't, please remove the tag.

Comment: OK, thank you  @XAMlMAX